# Tabhost intents

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I have a menu screen (Activity 'A') with multiple tabs in side a tabhost.
On clicking any of these tabs, a new Activity ('B') is launched. I associate an intent for each tab using the following:

```
public class AActivity extends TabActivity {...
```

{addScrollEntry called in loop to add multiple tabs...}

```
private void addScrollEntry(myObj p_myObj){
        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(),BActivity.class);
        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        setupTab(new TextView(this), p_myObj.someText, intent);
    }

private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag, Intent myIntent) {
    View tabview = createTabView(m_tabHost.getContext(), tag);
    TabSpec setContent =  m_tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(myIntent);
    m_tabHost.addTab(setContent);
}
```

The problem I am having:

If I click on a tab ('1'), it launches Activity 'B' = OK.

I then press 'back' on Activity  'B' to take me back to Activity 'A' = OK.

Now two possibilities:

(1) If I press a different tab, other than tab '1' (to also show Activity 'B'), and then 'back' and then click tab '1' again, it launches Activity 'B' OK.

(2) However - if I press the SAME tab '1' again, NOTHING happens. I have inserted debug on every possible activity on Activity 'A' (onCreate,OnResume,onNewIntent etc), including debug on m_tabHost events (onTabChanged, onClick, OnTouch) and nothing is showing.

It is almost as if a call to onTabChanged is required to 'reset' a tab.

Any ideas?

Comment: This approach to developing tabs in Android has been deprecated for nearly three years. Please use more modern tab techniques: `FragmentTabHost`, `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, action bar tabs, etc. Or, use `TabHost` and `TabWidget`, but without trying to nest activities.

Comment: Would making a shift to the newer approach have a negative impact on existing apps running on OS version 2+?

Comment: All of the options I cited are available for API Level 7 onwards.